# Is there a POSIX syscall to resolve file system paths?

Tags: unix, macos, posix, system-calls

Is there a POSIX syscall to resolve filesystem paths? I have the CWD for a path, as well as the path to a file from that CWD. I can't use `chdir` to switch to the directory because I need to resolve paths from multiple threads simultaneously. I considered appending a `/` in between the CWD and the path, but for some reason it feels like that's hacky. Is that the proper way to resolve relative paths?

Comment: `.//..///cwd///////file` is a perfectly acceptable posix path (although you probably don't want to display that to a user).

Comment: Do you want the _canonicalized_ path? E.g from `../../bin/../` to `/` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think appending the `/` should be sufficient in pretty much all situations - even with `.`,`..`, extra `/`s, or symlinks it should just do the right thing.  If you really want to do this with the standard library, you can use `realpath(3)` to do path normalization but I don't know of a way to do exactly what you want.

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants realpath(), +1

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you want to do with the file, and if relatively recent additions in POSIX.1-2008 are acceptable for you, `openat` and friends may be of interest:

```
int dirfd = open(desired_cwd_path, O_RDONLY);
int fd = openat(dirfd, file_relpath, O_RDONLY);
close(dirfd);
// ...use fd
```

(These system calls have existed on e.g. Solaris and Linux for quite some time.)

Comment: Sigh... not available on Mac OS X, at least as of 10.5.7.  Conversely, appropriately enough the Linux man page says "openat() and other similar system calls suffixed 'at' are supported for two reasons.  [...]  Second, openat() allows the implementation of a per-thread 'current working directory', via file descriptor(s) maintained by the application."